# nuxt: command not found | Having to use npx instead of npm

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, node-modules

I'm trying to create an SSG website with nuxt.js but when I try to run `nuxt build && nuxt export` or any other nuxt command in the VS Code terminal I get this error: `bash: nuxt: command not found`. I have these installed:

- node 12.18.2
- npm 6.14.6
- nuxt 2.13.3 (globally)
- I also run VS Code as an administrator on Windows 10

I can run the commands with this format: `npx nuxt build && npx nuxt export` (adding `npx` before nuxt), it's a quick fix but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried `npm cache clean --force`, deleted all `node_modules`, and the `package-lock.json` file. And after that ran `npm install` but to no success.

---

Edit. 16.10.2020

This issue is still persistent with other npm packages, like. Gridsome.

```
C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

Comment: are you running your cmds from same folder as package.json? sidenote dont use odd number node versions

Comment: Yeah I'm in the webroot when running all commands. I also tried to downgrade my node version to v12.18.2 but still same issue.

Comment: as i know when you want to run node packages you have to use `npm` or `npx`(or `yarn`). the reason of this is we use node to run scripts and your OS only knows node commands

and because you want to run  you have to add `run` to it like `npm run`.

next thing is the name of command and the name is defined in your `package.json` file in script section so for example when yo want to run nuxt on development you should do `npm run dev` (that defined in `package.json`)

Comment: Yeah I get that, and I'm able to run commands with the format ```npx nuxt dev``` I'd just like to know why I'm not able to just run the ```nuxt``` command instead.

Comment: @Krullmizter What was the exact command you used to install `nuxt`?

Comment: I used npx to create a nuxt project ```npx create-nuxt-app projectName```

Comment: That command sets up a project directory with nuxt installed locally only in that directory. You should just stick with the npm scripts provided in `package.json` (`npm run build`, etc ). If you want to run nuxt explicitly as in your example, you have to install it globally with `npm i -g nuxt`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the input but even if I try to install nuxt globaly with ```npm i -g nuxt``` I still get the error message of ```nuxt: command not found``` I'm just wondering if I have something bad configured.

Comment: I have had the same problem for over a year with my Nuxt projects. Npm and npx command works, but nuxt commands don't. So frustrating.. Did you get it solved somehow??

Comment: No I haven't managed to solve it yet. None of the answers here and on other posts have solved the issue.

Comment: Update: I installed Nuxt globally with npm i -g nuxt and now the Nuxt commands works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Static Generated Deployment (Pre-rendered)
Nuxt.js gives you the ability to host your web application on any static hosting.

To generate our web application into static files:

For Nuxt >= 2.13:

```
"scripts": {
    "generate": "nuxt build && nuxt export"
  }
```

In your nuxt.config file, you need to add the target property with the value of static nuxt.config.js

export default {
target: 'static'
}

As the doc says!

I've checked mine, and the command was there but with different content. Anyway just change the content of the command 'generate' as follows.

```
"generate": "nuxt build && nuxt export",
```

then you're good to go.
hope the answer helps.

Comment: Yeah I've tried doing that but to no success. I can't run any Nuxt command in the terminal.

Comment: I see what your problem is. try to get s sense of what docker is and how to use it. then use node version 10 for nuxt deploy.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you weren't able to run `nuxt` commands directly from the terminal is the `nuxt` package is **not installed globally**, therefore your terminal would not know of the existence of `nuxt`, despite having it installed locally.

If you do want to run the `nuxt` command, what you should do is to specify the `nuxt` package path from your local `node_modules` directory like so:

```sh
./node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js build # equivalent to npm run build or yarn build
./node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js start # equivalent to npm run start or yarn start
```

However, most of the times you don't want to install Nuxt as a global package, nor you'd want to run the `nuxt` commands directly. What you probably want to do is use `npm` or `yarn` to run the Nuxt commands for you based on what you specify under `"scripts"` in `package.json` like so:

```json
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

The corresponding commands are:

```sh
npm run build && npm run start
```

or

```sh
yarn build && yarn start
```

Comment: I do have it installed globally but this issue with not being able to run npm scripts directly without npx is a persistent issue on my machine.