# Having to run NPM package commands solely with NPX

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js, npx, gridsome

I've asked a similar question before ([nuxt: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864622/nuxt-command-not-found)), but now it's regarding gridsome. I've tried to run both nuxt and gridsomes's NPM packages directly in the VS Code terminal but I get the error: `bash: nuxt: command not found` / `bash: gridsome: command not found` I tried to reinstall node, and I run VS Code with administrative privileges.

I can run gridsome and nuxt with only the NPX command for them, ex. `npx gridsome create` so that isn't the problem, I'm just wondering what I could be doing wrong.

I asume this is either a node, npm and/or npx issue, due to that I can't run packages solely with their NPM package commands.

Now I've installed:

- Node 12.18.3
- NPM & NPX 6.14.7

Comment: these module installed globaly? `npm i -g`

Comment: Yeah they are. This problem only persists on my Windows 10 installation. Works great on Linux tho.